# Error using the print function inside a lambda function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a simple code in Python 2.7, but it is giving me syntax error.

```
hello = lambda first: print("Hello", first)
```

The error reported is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: `print()` is not a function in Python 2 unless you add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your script. Why are you trying to use it as a function?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The tutorial I was referring to was using the same. When I tried to mimic it, I got an error. I tried the same without the brackets like we normally do in python 2.7 but that failed too.

Comment: Your tutorial appears to be for Python 3; either switch tutorials or install Python 3, you'll have other problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python disallows the use of statements in [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

> Note that functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain
>   statements or annotations.

`print` is a statement in Python 2, unless you import the `print_function`  feature from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html):

```
>>> lambda x: print(x)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lambda x: print(x)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> lambda x: print(x)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f2ed301d668>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `lambda x: print(x) then 1+1` inside a lamda, where the `then` represents something that just drops the `None` type and returns the right expression?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I honestly can't think of a reason why you might want to do  this, but since `print` (the function) returns `None`, you can use the `or` operator: `lambda x: print(x) or other_value`.